# How to customize Strapi WYIWYG content editor?

Tags: strapi, draftjs, headless-cms

Strapi uses a rich text editor called Draftjs in its content editor which by default doesn't have anyway of embedding HTML snippets.  to add  the ability to embed HTML inside a post, I found this plugin [https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-draftjs].

in the documentation it mentions that the usage of the plugin is done like so...

```js
import { EditorState, ContentState } from 'draft-js';
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';

const blocksFromHtml = htmlToDraft(this.props.content);
const { contentBlocks, entityMap } = blocksFromHtml;
const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocks, entityMap);
const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
```

But I would greatly appreciate if someone more knowledgeable could tell me how exactly do I modify the backend files and where do I insert the code snippet above to get the plugin to work.